# Inline Image and Video -Windows Phone UWP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am having image source and video source in a string as below.

```
<div>புதுடெல்லி:</div><br /><br /><div>2014- நாடாளுமன்ற தேர்தல் </div><div><img src="/MMAdmin/uploads/8CAC42CC-D275-4589-9C91-2D005B2607FE_L_styvpf.gif" width="640" height="305" alt="" /></div><div><br /><div align="center"><object height="360"><embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rprTDfqFwtI" height="360px" width="100%" /></object></div></div></div>
```

I need to bind the string in Windows Phone UWP controls. I tried to bind in RichTextBlock. Inline image is binding properly, but video is not binding in RichTextBlock.

I bind the image and video using below methods

```
 private static Inline GenerateIFrame(HtmlNode node)
        {
            try
            {
                Span s = new Span();
                s.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());

                InlineUIContainer iui = new InlineUIContainer();

                int height = 160;
                int width = 300;

                WebView ww = new WebView();
                ww.Navigate(new Uri("http://video.ch9.ms/ch9/43df/9cf95ed5-b06f-4f9a-a216-983e107143df/ABSWP81Part20.mp4", UriKind.Absolute));
                ww.Height = 300;
                //ww.Width = 300;
                ww.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                ww.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

                //{
                //    Source = new Uri(node.Attributes["src"].Value, UriKind.Absolute)
                //    ,
                //    Width = width,
                //    Height = height
                //};

                iui.Child = ww;
                s.Inlines.Add(iui);
                s.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
                return s;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }


 private static Inline GenerateImage(HtmlNode node)
        {
            Span s = new Span();
            try
            {
                InlineUIContainer iui = new InlineUIContainer();
                var sourceUri = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(node.Attributes["src"].Value);
                Image img = new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(sourceUri, UriKind.Absolute)) };
                img.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
                img.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                img.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                img.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width - 15;
                iui.Child = img;
                s.Inlines.Add(iui);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return s;
        }
```

Please some one guide to solve the issue. I tried to put the whole string in Web view it produce page navigation unpleasant. Any help on this would be very helpful. Thanks in advance